# Why is my HttpHandler not being fired?

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, ihttphandler

I am trying to use a http hadler, so I created a class lirary project and added this code:

```
 namespace MyProject.Handlers
{
    public class Class1 : IHttpHandler
    {
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.Write("Hello from custom handler.");
        }
    }
}
```

Then I compiled it and it generated the MyProject.Handlers.dll file. I put it in my asp.net bin folder and added this to the asp.net

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="TutorialHandler" verb="*" path="*" type="MyProject.Handlers.Class1, MyProject.Handlers" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="File" />
    </handlers>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    //some stuff I *think* it doesn't make a difference
</modules>
//some stuff I *think* it doesn't make a difference
</system.webServer>
```

and

```
<system.web>
 <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*" type="MyProject.Handlers.Class1, MyProject.Handlers" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
```

But it just doesn't get called!
I start the debugger, set the breakpoint, but it doesn't stop. If I check the output html in firebug, the sentence "Hello from custom handler" is not there.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Oscar

EDIT: I'm using framework 4.0, IIS7. 
Could it be that I am using routes? (not calling directly index.aspx, but /home or something like this?)

Comment: Everything looks right... are you loading a page from the proper path?

Comment: Try changing path to "handler.ashx" and loading that specific page

Comment: What version of the .NET framework are you using?

Comment: @ic3berg I changed both path to home.aspx and and loaded localhost/home.aspx. It didn't work :(

Comment: try using the App_Code folder for the source files (not dll)

Comment: @Moe Framework 4.0 and IIS7,

Comment: probably you need to `<clear />` before you add your handler, in your config file

Comment: Did you add a reference to that dll?

Comment: Clear is there, DLL is referenced.
I added it to the beginning of my list an it loads, but I am having problems making the path value correct: I am using mvc routing, so I can't add *.aspx to the path. What value should I add?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it wasn't being called when it was at the end of the handlers list. I moved to the top and got a strange error regarding webresources.axd. The reson was the path="*".
I couldn't find a matching path because I am using routes.

At the end I found out that I was using the wrong tool: the modules were the right thing for me, not handlers, because I would like to add things to my output depending on the case. So I changed my approach to use modules instead and it now looks good.
Thanks to all that helped me with comments!